# Choosing a platform for developing opensource GIS web application.

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, java, php

I am from a non programming background. I started learning GIS opensource web applications from last 3 moths. Now I am using only notepad++ for writing codes and I am familiar with *javascript*, *HTML* and litle bit *PHP*.
My question is, 
              1.Can I develop a application without java or asp.net.
              2.If yes , text editor (notepad++) is sufficient or I have to go with eclips, netbeans or visualstudio.

Comment: Although your title refers to GIS, your question does not appear to be about GIS.  Could you please clarify how this relates to GIS?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using an IDE such as Eclipse rather than Notepad++. Once you've ascended the IDE learning curve, you will be more productive, and more employable (if that's a consideration).

I'm developing an Android Smartphone navigation application using Java and Eclipse, a combination which works well for me. It should be possible to develop a GIS web application using PHP, but I recommend using Eclipse for this.